# Regex to reject specific values

Tags: regex

How to reject specific characters/string in a regex? For example I want to allow numbers such as "123", "1982" or "3" but not "0".

Comment: Maybe regex is not your best option here.

Comment: What is so specific about `123`, `1982` and `3`? Sounds like `if (num > 0)`.

Comment: /[1-9]+ is what you asked for - but it may not be what you need. What code language? And what are you trying to do - please explain.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I am using a plugin that uses regex pattern. So regex is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow all integers, except 0 or a number with a leading zero, you can use the following regular expression:

```
^[1-9]\d*$
```

Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/DauRoh/1

---

This approach is only reasonable, if you have strings, which are representing numbers. In cases, where you have an integer number, you can check if the number is larger then `0`. Leading zeros are not a problem then.

```
num = 123;

if(num > 0) {
   console.log('greater than 0');
} else {
   console.log('lower or equal to 0');
}
```